# Cannot boot to SteamOS after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: boot, partitioning, ext4, 15.04, fsck

A quick overview of my system: I have Ubuntu, Windows 8.1, and a Debian-based OS (specifically [SteamOS](http://store.steampowered.com/steamos/)) all installed. All of them booted just fine before yesterday.

Yesterday, I upgraded to Vivid Vervet. Upon rebooting, I realized that the GRUB entries for SteamOS were missing. I tried reinstalling GRUB, with no luck.

Further investigation yielded some strange results. `/dev/sda5` is the boot partition for SteamOS.

Results of `fdisk`:

```
Device     Boot      Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1             2148  957177855 957175708 456.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1305270272 1323696127  18425856   8.8G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda3  *    1323696128 1465147391 141451264  67.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda4        957177856 1305266175 348088320   166G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5  *     978155520  999127039  20971520    10G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6        999129088 1020100607  20971520    10G 83 Linux
/dev/sda7       1020102656 1305266175 285163520   136G 83 Linux
/dev/sda8        957179904  978153471  20973568    10G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Results of `sudo fsck -vy /dev/sda5`:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.25.2
e2fsck 1.42.12 (29-Aug-2014)
/dev/sda5 is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.
```

And in GParted, `/dev/sda5` shows up as `unknown` filesystem type.

Also, previously I was able to see `/dev/sda5` in the sidebar of my file manager (I'm using Thunar). Now it has disappeared, although all the other partitions are still there.

What can I do to recover my SteamOS boot partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I ran `lsblk` and saw that there was a `cryptswap1` device under `/dev/sda5`. Sure enough, `/etc/crypttab` had the line

```
cryptswap1 /dev/sda5 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

I commented this line out, rebooted, and ran `fsck` on `/dev/sda5`, and this time it worked as expected.

I'm still not sure why this broke after the upgrade to 15.04, maybe something in a new version of `cryptsetup`. In any case, that line in `/etc/crypttab` wasn't doing anything anyways.